# PostgreSQL throwing error on RAISE NOTICE with || operator

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Getting the following error with the following line of code:

```
RAISE NOTICE '*** Rolling back job run id ' || CONVERT(varchar, v_job_run_id)
             || ' for table ' || v_table_name || '***';
```

Error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "|" LINE 43:   RAISE NOTICE '***
>   Rolling back job run id ' || CONVERT(var...

Comment: `||` is not the "pipe operator" but the standard SQL concatenation operator.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A message string in [`RAISE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html) XXXX statement should be literal constant - expression is not allowed there. It is similar to format string in printf like functions.

```sql
RAISE NOTICE 'my table has name %', tablename;
```

Second issue should be `CONVERT`, that is not supported in Pg - use [`CAST`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS) instead or nothing, any parameter of RAISE statement is converted to text automatically.

Comment: P.S. You do have to use `CAST` instead of `CONVERT`.

Comment: or in other words use `RAISE NOTICE '%', 'yada' || 'dada';`